# jQuery $(document).ready and svg-web window.onsvgload

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

jQuery of course requires everything to be inside

```
$(document).ready = function() {};
```

similarly, svg-web requires:

```
window.onsvgload = function() {};
```

Is there a correct, elegant way to combine these that doesn't introduce any problems?

Comment: how about pasting the contents of `onsvgload`

Comment: my entire script has to be run when the page is loaded (the first) and svg-web has loaded (the second) - the contents are, well, everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just bind the functions to run on the appropriate event, like this:

```
$(function() { //shortcut for $(document).ready(function() {
  //stuff that needs the DOM to be ready
});
$(window).bind('svgload', function() {
  //SVG stuff
});
```

There's no harm is using both, in fact that's the *appropriate* usage, always use the event you need, this is no different from `document.ready` vs `window.load` when you need images ready, not just the DOM.

If it matters, `svgload` happens *after* `onload` in the browsers that support it as of the time of this answer, not sure if that'll be consistent when other browsers support it though.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still kind of confused. Where do I put stuff that needs both?

Comment: @colinmarc: `svgload` will fire after the DOM is ready, since it's dependent, if it needs both put it in the `.bind('svgload')` call...the SVG elements have to be setup and loaded at that point, so the DOM was ready before then.  If it only needs the DOM, stick with `document.ready`.

Comment: this actually gave me some problems - I ended up going with what I posted below - but I'll leave the answer thing because you really helped me understand what was going on

Answer (score 1):

Finally found this in the 'user manual':

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.addEventListener('SVGLoad', function() {
       // ready to work with SVG now
    }, false);
});
```

Comment: This isn't cross-browser compatible.  You should use jquery's bind method or create a function to decide whether or not to use addEventListener, attachEvent, or to set window.onsvgload.