# Using svgweb to detect when svg object is loaded?

Tags: jquery, svg

I'm trying to detect when an svg object is loaded on my page, using the svgweb plugin, to then get the value of an attribute inside the svg. I tried this that I found in the documentation:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    window.addEventListener('SVGLoad', function() {
      alert('done');
    }, false);
  });
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I chose this version of the various ways to check, since I'm using the document ready function for other jQuery after this. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to add something else?

EDIT: Oh, and BTW, this doesn't work either: [jQuery $(document).ready and svg-web window.onsvgload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008229/jquery-document-ready-and-svg-web-window-onsvgload)

Comment: I'm not sure if such an event really exists. Maybe you could create the SVG with libraries like http://raphaeljs.com/?

Comment: I am using a library/plugin: svgweb. That's where the event comes from. I just don't understand how to get it to work.

Comment: Do you have a svgweb object anywhere? Maybe you could use this event on it?

Comment: @Armin: how do you mean? I have a script reference to the svgweb plugin, and then the docs said to check if SVG is loaded as described above. But that didn't work. The svg files are included in <object> elements...

Answer (score 0):

You need to call addEventListener on the outer svg element and not the window. SVG events don't go to the window unlike html.

If you've got an svg document rather than a html5 one with svg in it you can get the outer svg element using document.documentElement otherwise put an id on the outer svg element and call document.getElementById to get it.

```
var svgElement = document.getElementById("<outer svg element id>");
svgElement.addEventListener("SVGLoad", ...
```

Comment: I have object elements to include svg files with the data attribute. I cannot change the svg files themselves, because these are generated all the time in a different environment (this is a technical documentation system). And I cannot really get to the svg element by id, because I will not know that id beforehand (this is done from a huge xslt transformation). I can get to the object element, and then I want to select the svg inside it when I know it's loaded...

Comment: In your case var svgElement = document.getSVGDocument().documentElement;

Comment: This is, what I have meant in the comments of the question :)